# Auto Browser History Flush

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, browser-history

I have a html page which generates data into a graph using PHP. The problem I have is that the web browser stores the history of the page.

This is a problem because I redirect my page to a second page every 5 mins. I use this method to alternate between two screens and also because my data is updated real-time.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300; url=myurl.html">
```

The issue being that after a number of refreshes, the history is saved and the updated information is no longer updated. It just keeps showing the two pages with old info.

How can I force these two pages to flush their history / browsing data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers

Answer (score 0):

These tags do seem to have resolved my issue across browsers

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-store"> 
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
```